# eclipse plugin:How to call actionSet with actionID

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Now I want to call an actionset which is defined in another plugin,I already have the actionId,But I don't know how to call it.

Here is the actionset:

```
<action
           class="com.src.action1"
           icon="action1.png"
           id="com.src.action1"
           label="action1"
           style="push"
           toolbarPath="new.ext">
</action>
```

I know that I can call command by commandId like this  :

```
IHandlerService handlerService = 
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
            handlerService.executeCommand(COMMANDID, null);
```

So I want to know if the toolbar button is defined by actionSet,can I call it like command by actionId?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can call it programmatically if the action doesn't define a command id using `definitionId`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to add your action to an existing action set or include an existing action into your action set?
Also, action and actions sets are deprecated, you should use commands instead: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

Comment: I know that I can call command by commandId like this  :

     IHandlerService handlerService = 
     PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    handlerService.executeCommand(COMMANDID, null);

So I want to know if the toolbar button is defined by actionSet,can I call it like command by actionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions are only connected to a command if they have a `definitionId` parameter. For example this action from the JDT plugin:

```xml
<action
     allowLabelUpdate="true"
     style="toggle"
     toolbarPath="org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.presentation/Presentation"
     id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.toggleMarkOccurrences"
     definitionId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.toggleMarkOccurrences"
     disabledIcon="$nl$/icons/full/dtool16/mark_occurrences.png"
     icon="$nl$/icons/full/etool16/mark_occurrences.png"
     helpContextId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.toggle_mark_occurrences_action_context"
     label="%toggleMarkOccurrences.label"
     retarget="true"
     tooltip="%toggleMarkOccurrences.tooltip">
</action>
```

In this example the command id is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.toggleMarkOccurrences`. So you would execute it using:

```java
handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.toggleMarkOccurrences", null);
```

If there is no `definitionId` parameter the action is not associated with a command and you cannot call it through the handler service.

Comment: So if there is a definitionId, I can use it by handlerService.executeCommand()?

Comment: The definitionId is the same as the command Id so you use it where you have `COMMANDID` in your example code. See update to answer.